# Creating a decision tree based on two columns

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, decision-tree

I am using Spark for some large data processing. But I think this problem is kind of independent. I have following data set with some other columns:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Name      | Corrected_Name                     |
--------------------------------------------------
| Pawan     | Varun                              |
--------------------------------------------------
| Varun     | Naresh                             |
--------------------------------------------------
| Dona      | Pia                                |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now I am trying to correct all the names so in this case I will have to find the chain Pawan -> Varun -> Naresh. Is there a way tto handle this in Spark or some other algorithm?

Comment: `Pawan->Varun->Naresh` means that all `Pawan` and `Varun` will be `Naresh` now? If yes, then just find the deepest child and replace all parents with this child value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that names are **commonly a bad identifier due to frequent duplication**. If you would eventually have to "squash" the chain (transform 2 rows into one), reducing by name itself will cause chaos.

Regarding the original question, this is a common case where iterative calculations should be made, this type of use-case has two possible directions:

1. In memory (assumptions should be made over the data) - collect all the data into a single machine, perform the mapping in memory and [Broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast) the result to other machines.
2. Distributed mapping (assumes nothing about the data, very expensive) - perform distributed next step-lookup, can be optimized to perform up to log(n) `join-cache-count` operations

pyspark code example for (2):

```
forward = get_all_data()
current_count = -1
while(current_count != 0):
    forward = forward.selectExpr("Name", "Corrected_Name as original_last_name", "Corrected_Name as connection").join(forward.selectExpr("Corrected_Name as Corrected_Name_Tmp", "Name as connection"), "connection", "left")
    forward_clean = forward.withColumn("Corrected_Name", merge_udf(col("original_last_name"), col("Corrected_Name_Tmp"))).cache()
    current_count = forward_clean.filter(forward_clean.Corrected_Name_Tmp.isNotNull()).count()
    forward = forward_clean.drop(col("original_last_name")).drop(col("Corrected_Name_Tmp")).drop(col("connection"))
```

This code results in all rows, each one has a mapping from original "Name" to last element in the "Corrected_Name" chain.

Note: (2) is very wasteful but assumes nothing, it can be optimized to perform at log(n) by making looking harder, looking can be optimized if you need only the first element in each chain. (1) is preferred calculation-size but you will have to benchmark the memory footprint